# What are all the components used in this sketch?

Tags: components, how-does-it-work

I am trying my hand at electronics.  Here's the sketch of a device I'd like to build that I found online.  It's for a coil gun.  I just don't know enough to understand the full sketch.

I've been researching this for several days now.  I'm hoping someone on here can help me.

I've determined I need the following.  What am I missing?

- switch
- 2 1M ohms resistors
- 1 microF Capacitor
- 1 electromagnetic coil
- 1 NPN transistor

[image]

Comment: 70A? Not a great beginner project.

Comment: I don't have to build it to that Amp level, if I can understand this stuff, I can build at a smaller power scale right?

Comment: @MVCylon: Performance is directly related to the amount of current. So scaling it down might enable smaller objects to be shot. Take a look at my answer, it has a link to several projects. That should be very helpful.

Comment: I forgot to mention...my end goal is a particle accelarator like coil gun, with several coils in a row, each increasing the velocity of the last coild...

Comment: I don't want to build this as 70A. more like 1.3A does that mean the size of the capacitor needs to be scaled down as well?

Comment: FWIW, the guy who [came up with this circuit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mdZo_keUoEs) is an 'engineering comedian', i.e. he does bad stuff on purpose.

Answer (score 4):

My advice is not to start with this, or at least minaturise it - 70A is a huge amount of current to be pulsing through a coil, and some pretty nasty things could happen if you get things wrong (burns, explosions, electrocution, etc)

If you really want to make it, I'd start with the same circuit, but make the coil and current smaller (use a small bank of AA cells or something, keep the current under 5A or so) It will still work with a small coil, just be less powerful but much safer, and you will still learn as much whilst large designing it.

You need a (reasonably hefty - check the maximum Id specs in the datasheet) N-ch MOSFET for the coil switch, and an optocoupler as Gustavo has mentioned.
The reverse biased diode across the coil as Wouter mentions is a very good idea, certainly if it's your first project of this type (otherwise seriously high voltages can appear at the drain of the MOSFET - we are talking possibly in the region of a few kV, so please be careful and start with low currents)

A resistor in series with the diode will actually increase the current discharge speed, but you need to calculate it carefully (it depends on the current switched, how fast, and the coil and MOSFET specs). [This coilgun related page](http://www.coilgun.eclipse.co.uk/switching_devices.html) discusses switching an inductive load. If you are not sure about the resistor value, don't include it.

Do a lot of reading before you start out, don't rush things, be safe, and have fun ;-)

Comment: Based on this sketch then, could you tell me what size resistors and capacitors i would need for a 1Amp version?

Comment: You can use the same values, the circuit will still work with any lower current.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a diode somewhere in case the FET suddenly wants to cut that 70A to 0?

Comment: Yes, good point - I think a diode plus resistor in there to limit voltage to a safe level would be a good idea, although I think if the coil is designed correctly, a high voltage MOSFET is used, and there is a load in there on firing, the transient shouldn't peak that high (although I have never designed a coil gun before, so I may be wrong) No reason not to implement it though, given it's cheap and easy.

Answer (score 1):

At the top, the led and transistor combo is an optocoupler. Perhaps 4N25(you need to check the spec to make sure it fits).  The last piece is an N channel MOSFET.

My best advice for you is to take a look at some nice [coil gun projects](http://hackaday.com/?s=coil%20gun) and see if you can get more information about components.

Comment: That octocoupler detects the bullet leaving the electro magnet and shuts off the magnet...would that prebuilt component handle that same task?

Comment: @MVCylon Usually optocoupler is a single component in one package. It's used for isolation and you can't push thighs through it. You'll need to make one using discrete components. The term you may want to use for search is "photocell" for example. Optocoupler is used for components where both the LED and transistor are in single package.

Comment: Thanks.  I was headed in the right direction then, I bought an infrared emitter and detector....

Comment: @MVCylon  Question in the O.P.: "What am I missing?"  You seem to be missing the parameters of the coil, most of all.  Try to find plans which provide details for the construction of the coil.